# Regex to allow only 9 or 10 characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

9 characters requires 2 letters in the beginning i.e ab1234567 and 10 characters needs to have all digits i,e 1234567890. How do I do this using regex?

Here is what I have tried.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{7}|[\d]{10}$/
```

This doesnt seem to work. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: could you show some examples for what should pass and what shouldn't?

Comment: @connor I don't think that's really necessary, given that the intent is clear as day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `|` in your regex allows it to match either of these two possibilities:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]{7}

[\d]{10}$
```

That is, start of string then 2 letters and seven numbers followed by anything, or anything followed by 10 numbers and end of string. Try this:

```
/^([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{7}|\d{10})$/
```

(Note also that I've removed the `[]` from around each `\d` - there's no point having a character class with only one character in it.)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the `^` is only applying the first option, and the `$` only applies to the second one.

Try this:

```
/^(?:[a-z]{2}\d{7}|\d{10})$/i
```